# Задачи с моделями памяти

Tags: c, память

объясните пожалуйста, как решать такие задачи с моделями памяти:

> 1. Установлена модель памяти COMPACT. Какой объем памяти будет занимать переменная `pd` согласно описанию `float *pd[5];`?
> 2. Установлена модель памяти MEDIUM. Какой объем памяти будет занимать переменная `a` согласно описанию `char *a[5][2];`?
> 3. Установлена модель памяти SMALL Имеется описание `int a[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, *p = a+2;` Какие из следующих выражений имеют значение 2?
>
>    1. `(int)p - (int)a;`
>    2. `p - a`
>    3. `*p - *a`;
>    4. `(a[1] + *p) / 2`

Comment: "Модели памяти" - сильно компиляторно-зависимая фича из времен DOS/Win16. Знать, что такое сегментная организация памяти надо обязательно, но вот зачем разбираться в старинной компиляторно-зависимой номенклатуре - не ясно. В любом случае: о каком компиляторе идет речь? Без этого вопрос бессмыслен (кроме, разве что, последнего, ибо он от модели памяти почти не зависит)

Comment: ""Модели памяти" - сильно компиляторно-зависимая фича из времен DOS/Win16." так на контрольной и напишу )

Comment: Песня про "фича из времен DOS/Win16" являлась увертюрой к конкретному вопросу: о каком компиляторе идет речь?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://pointersinclanguage.blogspot.com/2012/11/memory-model-in-c-programming_1470.html) приводят вот такую таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И дано такое пояснение:

- в колонке Code - указатели на функции;
- в колонке Data - указатели на переменные;

Указатели `near` занимают 2 байта, указатели `far` - 4 байта.

---

Теперь, возвращаясь к вашим вопросам. Поскольку у вас нету указателей на функции, то всегда смотрим в колонку Data:

1. Массив из 5-ти `far` указателей на `float`, т.е. 5 * 4 = 20 байт;
2. Двумерный массив из 10-ти `near` указателей на `char`, т.е. 10 * 2 = 20 байт;
3. Массив из 10 интов и один `near` указатель, но размерность указателя на ответ никак не влияет. Правильные ответы: 2, 3, 4.

Comment: В первых двух вопросах - массивы, а не указатели. Вопрос 1: `pd` - массив из 5 far указателей = 20 байт. Вопрос 2: `a` - массив из 10 near указателей = 20 байт. В последнем вопросе подразумевается множественный ответ. Варианты 2, 3 и 4 заведомо входят в ответ при любой модели памяти. Вопрос только о том, входит ли 1. По-видимому нет.

Comment: @AnT А разве массивы сами по себе не указатели? Переменная `pd` содержит адрес памяти, по которому расположено столько-то элементов, такого-то типа и т.д.

Comment: Нет массивы в С и С++ - не указатели и никогда указателями не являлись. Переменная `pd` - это просто блок из `5` указателей `float *`. Она не "содержит адрес памяти".

Comment: Исправил ответ.